# how to call $auth on nuxt typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
<script lang="ts">
import LoginAdmin from '@/components/LoginAdmin.vue'
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import  Auth  from "@nuxtjs/auth";

export default class MyStore extends Vue {


public username:string="";
  public password:string="";
  public error:string="";
  async login(){
   
    try {

        await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: {
          email: this.username,
          password: this.password
          },
        })
console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn)
        // this.$router.push('/')
      } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
      }
  }
}

</script>
```

I use typescript as the script language in nuxt but i haven't got the luck to call **this.$auth** how can i call it inside **class** on typescript nuxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

i have found the answer myself for everybody who is struggling with this also you can add nuxt-property-decorator to your package.json then add @Component to your class like this :

```
@Component
export default class MyStore extends Vue {
```

now you can use $auth

Answer (score 0):

And for everyone who is [using the `Options API` of Nuxt and TypeScript](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/components), use it like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  middleware: ['auth'],
  methods: {
    async login(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            let res = await this.$auth.loginWith('google');
            console.log("login result: " + res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("login error: " + err);
        }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```